# Recording livestream from m3u8 to pipe using ffmpeg results in video with no audio

Tags: ffmpeg, pipe, mpeg

I'm not very good with ffmpeg, so this code is something I've created through trial and error.
I'm using ffmpeg from VB.net with the arguments:

`Dim CL As String = "-y -i " & Chr(34) & URL & Chr(34) & " -t " & Time & " -acodec copy -vcodec copy -f mpeg pipe:pipe1"`

The videos end up having no audio. I tried removing '-acodec copy' and '-vcodec copy' and using '-map 0', which creates a video with audio, but the quality is substantially lower. I'd like to retain the quality and still have audio.

Answer (score 1):

After trawling the documentation, I found that there's a format called mpegts (which appears to be the one of the files m3u8 contains), so I tried changing the code to

`Dim CL As String = "-y -i " & Chr(34) & URL & Chr(34) & " -t " & Time & " -acodec copy -vcodec copy -f mpegts pipe:pipe1"`

And it's retaining the quality and has audio.